# Is it forbidden to have a wedding by the koisel (western wall)?

Tags: halacha, marriage, kotel-western-wall, chupah

Someone told me that I can't get married by the koisel.

Is this true?

If yes what is the reason, (religious (then sources please) or practical...)?

Comment: There isn't really any religious significance to the area there other perhaps than that of a Shul. Perhaps there are local Israeli laws about it? Perhaps you can't reserve the space?

Comment: I have seen references which state "Weddings are not allowed at the Kotel for any religion" This seems to imply that it is more of a political matter as well as practical. Consider that the bride would be on the wrong side of the mechitzah as well.

Comment: http://myday.ynet.co.il/en/blog/lisa-marks-jerusalemtel-aviv-wedding/#.VcJtl_mnyM8 Has a blog by someone who says that she was married "at the kotel" however, the description *I had been to Jerusalem 9 times, but for some reason never on this 1 balcony that provided a stunning view of the Kotel.* seems to imply that it was not in the kotel plaza but a bacony overlooking it. The picture of the chupah http://hatunotblog.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/en/files/2012/09/13465293637116.jpeg seems to also imply that it was just a minyon at a side location.

Comment: http://www.jpost.com/LifeStyle/The-Wedding-Planner-Destination-Israel-321748 *Jerusalem has several locations that are breathtaking such as Esh Hatora rooftop overlooking the Kotel* also implies that weddings are not done at the kotel itself.

Comment: Well, if Jews can get married, there, then you'd have Christians and Muslims who'd also want to

Comment: @user613 I do not see Muslims, and Christians making there group prayers there why are weddings different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like others, I couldn't think of a single halachic reason to forbid weddings. I know I've seen dozens of [Bar Mitzvahs](http://barmitzva.thekotel.org/) over the years there, but never a wedding. (On Monday and Thursday around mid morning it seems like there's a bar mitzvah every 20 minutes). I did some digging and eventually found the [rabinate's rules for the kotel](http://english.thekotel.org/content.asp?Id=320), and it is true that they forbid both weddings and britot at the kotel. (They also have lots of rules around sound amplification). It appears to be a rule based on purely practical reasons.

Somewhat tangentially it is common (common? Okay maybe not common but certainly not unheard of) for brides to go to the kotel before their wedding to pray, often times in their wedding dress (which usually elicits lots of "mazal tov"s from onlookers). The Temple Institute even [cites a tradition](https://www.templeinstitute.org/guide_to_ascending_the_mount.htm) for a bride to ascend to the temple mount after her first mikvah immersion.